# NodeJS, Express Application deployment to Heroku error

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, deployment

```
2021-07-21T10:35:36.685068+00:00 app[web.1]:     at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:650:9)
2021-07-21T10:35:36.685069+00:00 app[web.1]:     at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:691:18)
2021-07-21T10:35:36.685069+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:805:11)
2021-07-21T10:35:36.685069+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:88:40)
2021-07-21T10:35:36.685069+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:241:28)
2021-07-21T10:35:36.685070+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:72:40)
2021-07-21T10:35:36.685070+00:00 app[web.1]:     at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:71:36) {
2021-07-21T10:35:36.685070+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
2021-07-21T10:35:36.685070+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-07-21T10:35:36.689475+00:00 app[web.1]: [31m[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...[39m
2021-07-21T10:36:10.234981+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-07-21T10:36:10.321258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-07-21T10:36:10.440568+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-07-21T10:36:33.443960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-07-21T10:36:33.487373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-07-21T10:36:33.570472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2021-07-21T10:36:33.679642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-21T10:36:34.530501+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=memories----project.herokuapp.com request_id=caecee65-f7d1-4001-b7dd-6b8a102da67e fwd="208.107.191.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-07-21T10:36:49.780060+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=memories----project.herokuapp.com request_id=6d042665-d3a9-4599-a898-9eb31ef5324b fwd="208.107.191.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-07-21T10:36:50.297023+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=memories----project.herokuapp.com request_id=f76edd9e-20ff-4976-bcf3-3f5262977904 fwd="208.107.191.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I've tried deploying this application a lot of times on Heroku but I can't seem to understand what the issue is. Application works just fine on my localhost but it has issues on deployed to Heroku.

Comment: This is only a partial log output. Have you tried running heroku logs --tail (through CLI)?

Comment: I'm able to get the application working now but only because I've let access to any ip address on mongoDB. How could I change that.

Comment: or I'm I supposed to give access to everyone? I've never deployed a mongo app before.

Comment: Those are entirely different questions than the one you have asked here and I would recommend that you open a new question.

Comment: I figured out the error is what I was trying to say, it was a database access error. Heroku couldnt retrieve my data from mongo because it wasnt whitelisted. thanks for trying to help.